# Get contacts updated / created after a time in address book

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

I am building a app that imports the phone contacts' email to the app. Instead import the whole phone address book every time, I want only import the updated/created one after last updating time. Is there a way to do it?

I tried to look around but didn't find any related information.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: probably, you need to remember the contact unique id, compare the mail value(s) and adopt changes..

Comment: thanks for the advice. If this the case, I already have this functionality ready. It sounds more resource consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as answer:
Probably, you need to remember the contact unique id, compare the mail value(s) and adopt changes..

Explanation:
Since the contacts API doesn't know, what you do with the data, there is no other way. Basically that's how updates work, right. Someone needs to know, what's already there. And in this case that's only your own code.